# Transmission-daemon use a lot of cache memory

Tags: debian, transmission, torrent-client

Can someone tell me why there is so much use of cache in my orange-pi when is running transmission-daemon, i'm not understanding really well if the problem is transmission-daemon or the cache used is for something else.
Maybe is normal that the usage is so high? Should i worry?
[image]

Comment: Tag "debian" and no Ubuntu version mentioned: we don't support debian. Ubuntu only, Oh and cache is there to be used.

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to apply to packaging issues OR workflow issues with Debian-Ubuntu; please clarify?  You've provided no clear OS and your tag state workflow/packaging (debian) related.

Answer (score 1):

`transmission` does a lot of I/O.

Cache is used to speed up I/O.

Use of cache (which can be released at need) is a Good Thing - unused RAM is a waste of power.